# Get file size during generate in QT

Tags: qt, filesize, qthread, qfileinfo

I need get the File size while it is being generated.

I've tried using QThread and `QFileInfo::size` and a `while` with a flag that signals when the finished file, but the value never changes.

So was wondering if you can take the file size while it is being generated.

Comment: please provide more details. how is the file generated or who is generating it? your application, or any process on the system? also, if you're trying to watch any file by any application, then don't forget that the file size can be somewhat unreliable, since the application could already have written something that is still cached somewhere and hasn't reached the actual file system yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qfileinfo.html):

> Note: To speed up performance, QFileInfo caches information about the file. Because files can be changed by other users or programs, or even by other parts of the same program, there is a function that refreshes the file information: refresh(). If you want to switch off a QFileInfo's caching and force it to access the file system every time you request information from it call setCaching(false).

So try the `QFileInfo::refresh()` function before (re-)checking the file size.

Comment: It worked exactly as expected , thank you TWE.